# How is it possible for a website to hide page style sheets?

Tags: css, resources, stylesheet

A moment ago, I was reading a [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) tutorial on styling the scroll bar. I navigated to the demo, and proceeded to view the page's source styles in Dev Tools, however I found the CSS file listed to be blank.

---

[image]

---

I moved to [the page's](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/) source, and clicked on [the link to the style sheet](http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/css/style.css), in the header, and to my surprise, I was shown this:

---

[image]

---

I'm curious to know how it's possible to serve the browser a proper style-sheet, which it utilizes to style the page, and then serve the client a spoof resource.

---

1. How is this done?
2. If I wanted to look at this file, could I do it? How?
3. Can this be done for other resources, such as JavaScript?

Comment: the css content is directly in the html file. the css file does not exist.

Comment: The CSS shown in a big black box, right click and inspect that. It is a real style tag.

Comment: In your very own screenshot with dev console up you can see the red error that says the file can not be found giving a 404 error.  You can reproduce that same image by typing a bogus URL after css-tricks.com.  It's just Chris Coyiers custom 404 page.

Comment: Ok, so in my situation, I misunderstood. In case the question might still offer some value, I'll leave it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume he's sending the user to a chosen page whenever they try to access any .css filetype. This can be done by editing the .htaccess with something like this..

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*\.css$ /custompage.html [R=301,L]
```

You can still access the CSS just not directly, try looking at it using the developer tools of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [site](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess10.shtml) explains it well:
It is possible to forbid hotlinking to files with a specific ending of a server by writing some lines of code in the .htaccess file.
with this way you can forbid or redirect every request for files which ending is registered.

Some imagesites (e. g. sites with wallpapers) use this to redirect image-hotlinks to the site the image is presented.

You can do that with .css, too.